# how do i do to configure user consent in ngx-google-analytics?

Tags: angular, google-analytics

i want to enable/disable this followings props using ngx-google-analytics in Angular v17:

```
ad_storage
analytics_storage
ad_user_data
ad_personalization
functionality_storage
personalization_storage
security_storage
```

there is a method in GoogleAnalyticsService to achieve that?